# О чём они общаются!?

Tags: клиент-сервер

Как посмотреть (какой программой), какой информацией обмениваются Клиент с Сервером? Ну, к примеру, веб-сервер с браузером, хотя вопрос стоит для протокола неизвестной архитектуры...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этой задачи можно использовать [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Ну уж лучшие это очень уж громко сказано. Однако, это ответ ;)

Comment: А какие еще утилиты можете предложить? Ничего более интересного, чем данный продукт я не видел.

Comment: Ну, всё зависит от потребностей и целей. Мне вот и tcpdump'а хватает, тогда как понятие "интересного" - субъективно.

Comment: Тут тревога NaN. Не хотите ли переписать ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Уже достаточно долгое время я не использую WireShark, то есть сказать что–либо про него сейчас не могу. Сделал ответ общим. Надеюсь коллеги, работающие с инструментом в настоящее время помогут улучшить ответ!